# Help me with this, completely bounded, relatively compact, c0,...

Tags: calculus, compactness

Given $c_0$ is the set of all sequences $x=(x_n)$ such that $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } {x_n} = 0$.
Let $||x|| = \mathop {\max }\limits_n |{x_n}|$ and $d(x,y)=||x-y||.$
Prove that $K \subset {c_0}$ is relatively compact $ \Leftrightarrow \mathop {\sup }\limits_{x \in K} ||x||$ $< $ $+\infty $ and $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \mathop {\sup }\limits_{x \in K} \mathop {\max }\limits_{n \le i < \infty } |{x_i}| = 0$.

My idea is trying to prove K is completely bounded (due to the fact that $c_0$ is complete) and by suppose K is not bounded, then I create a sequence $(x_n)$
such that $d(x_n,x_m)≥r$
for all  $n,m$.

Comment: Please provide your attempts and more context.

Comment: Well I try to prove K is completely bounded by suppose K is not bounded, then I create a sequence $(x_n)$ such that $d(x_n, x_m) \ge r$ for all $n, m$.

Comment: Flesh that out as much as you can and put it in the question